# Using the cuckoo analysis sample，the virtual machine: error getting access to process: 5

Tags: linux, windows

When I finished the installation of cuckoo，I use cuckoo analysis samples. But there is a mistake in the virtual machine.

[image]

Cuckoo displays the following pages：

[image]

My host uses ubuntu 14.04 and virtualbox 5.2.
How to solve this problem?